# Apache Camel-k metrics in rancher embedded prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, rancher

I have a Kubernetes running Rancher 2.4.3. I have the cluster monitoring enabled in rancher, so that exists a Prometheus instance running, so as a  Prometheus Operator.

Recently I deployed a Apache Camel-K operator, and now I want to enable the prometheus integration for collect metrics about my camel routes.

So, my Camel-K operator is running in namescape `camel-k` and the rancher embedded prometheus stack in `cattle-prometheus` namespace.

I just have launched my route with the trait `--trait prometheus.enabled=true`, but the camel metrics aren't listing at my prometheus.

Anyone knows why or what I need to configure to my camel-k route deploy it's metrics at the rancher embedded prometheus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved updating the prometheus operator 0.38.1 -> 0.39.0.

More details: https://github.com/apache/camel-k/issues/2794